# fread is reading the last part of my text file twice

Tags: c++, windows, file, stat

I have a text file I want to read into an `std::vector`.  It's okay if the vector is a little too big, but it seems to be doing a very weird thing:  It's copying the entire file, then copying a portion of the file near the end twice and appending it. (I think this might simply be garbage, but I don't know.)

So if the file looked like this (it's a pretty large `txt` file):

```
0kb        100kb       200kb      300kb   
 v          v           v           v
[1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]
```

The copy in memory looks like this:

```
0kb        100kb       200kb      300kb   302kb
 v          v           v           v     v
[1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ TUVW]
                              ^^^^ this section is repeated at the end
```

I'm not entirely sure what's causing it, the code I wrote to perform this copy is this.

- I first use `stat` to attain a size that can hold the file, in bytes.  This might end up being larger due to how windows does line endings.
- I allocate my memory.
- Using `fread()` I copy the file into the vector in one shot.

```
void copyFile(std::vector<char> & output, const char * filename) {
    output.clear();
    FILE * file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!file)
        return;
    {
        struct stat statBuffer;
        stat(filename, &statBuffer);
        output.resize(statBuffer.st_size + 1);
        fread(output.data(), 1, statBuffer.st_size, file);
        output[statBuffer.st_size] = 0;  // make sure it's null terminated
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

My theory is that `fread()` is reading past the end of the file and copying garbage?  I am expecting `fread()` to read `n` bytes from the file, but perhaps that argument refers to `n` bytes *outputted* instead?  These values would differ since it's reading 2 bytes for each newline, then outputting 1...  But I can't find any information on this.  Nor would I know how to handle that without breaking my read operation into a bunch of really tiny "getline()" commands.  But maybe that's just necessary?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If (it’s a CRLF file and) `fread` is writing fewer bytes than it reads, _you’re_ reading past the end of what it wrote.  It tells you how much it read; isn’t that enough?

Comment: @DavisHerring - OH, it really was that easy... uint32 cnt = fread(...); output[cnt] = 0;  That fixed me up good, thank you!

Comment: You really should open the file in binary mode `fopen(filename, "rb")` then line endings are not a problem.

Comment: @AnneQuinn on a side note: since you are coding in C++, is there a reason why you are using C's `fread()` function instead of using C++'s `std::(i)fstream` class?

Comment: Is there a need for the terminating 0 char? Usually I'd implement the reading part as `if(auto readSize = std::fread(); readSize == 0) {... error handling ... } else { output.resize(readSize); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always check the **return** values of I/O functions.  One sufficient reason is to check for errors, but when `fread` might store fewer bytes than it reads (*e.g.*, on Windows with files open in the default text mode), the return value is how you know how much was **stored** and thus how much of the buffer to use.

The apparent repetition of data at the end of the buffer is evidence of an implementation strategy of reading into the buffer in binary mode and then shifting characters back to hide the carriage returns.  This isn’t significant to a correct program, but it makes sense that the standard library would make use of the provided buffer this way.